# Scan for a nested Map inside a List that don't exist

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-dynamodb

I would like some help with structuring a scan via AWS CLI to get results where the "on_demand" map does not exist. The "on_demand" map is nested in other parent maps [0 , 1, 2...]. Which in turn are in the playlist List.

The conditions for the scan would be where is_offsite = true, video_type = OFFSITE and of course the troublesome condition where the "on_demand" map does not exist.

This is my table structure.

```
{
"Items": [
    {
        "playlist": {
            "L": [
                {
                    "M": {
                        "duration": {
                            "N": "46"
                        },
                        "on_demand": {
                            "M": {
                                "bucket": {
                                    "S": "s3 Bucket"
                                },
                                "key": {
                                    "S": "bucket url to video file"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "download": {
                            "M": {
                                "bucket": {
                                    "S": "s3 bucket"
                                },
                                "key": {
                                    "S": "bucket url to video file"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "S": "on_demand"
                        }
                    },
                    "M": {
                        "duration": {
                            "N": "60"
                        },
                        "on_demand": {
                            "M": {
                                "bucket": {
                                    "S": "s3 Bucket"
                                },
                                "key": {
                                    "S": "bucket url to video file"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "download": {
                            "M": {
                                "bucket": {
                                    "S": "s3 bucket"
                                },
                                "key": {
                                    "S": "bucket url to video file"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "S": "on_demand"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "video_type": {
            "S": "OFFSITE"
        },
        "id": {
            "S": "random hash id"
        },
        "is_offsite": {
            "BOOL": true
        },
    }
]
}
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was accomplished by using the following:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name table-name \
--projection-expression "id" \
--filter-expression 'is_offsite = :os AND video_type = :vt AND attribute_not_exists(playlist[0].on_demand)' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":os": { "BOOL": true},":vt": {"S": "OFFSITE"}}'
```